# Impact of hyperref, when varioref and cleveref are used

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, incompatibility, cleveref, varioref

I think I may have found a bug in either `hyperref`, `cleveref`oder `varioref` but can't determine the details any further. If do not load `hyperref` in the following example, the result is fine.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{babel}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Erster Abschnitt}\label{sec}

\begin{figure}
\rule{\textwidth}{1cm}
\caption{bild}\label{bild}
\end{figure}

Siehe \vref{sec}, siehe \vref{bild}

\end{document}
```

[image: good results without hyperref]

If I load `hyperref` the reference reference to the section cannot be expanded, I get the following error instead:

```
! Argument of \@fourthoffive has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.19 Siehe \vref{sec}
                     , siehe \vref{bild}
?
```

[image: bad results with hyperref]

Any idea from which package this error may result?

Comment: for future reference [which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before)

Comment: also very closely related [Difference between ref, varioref and cleveref. Decision for a thesis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83037)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Load `varioref` first, then `hyperref`, then `cleveref`. See section 14.1 of the `cleveref` manual.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Erster Abschnitt}\label{sec}

\begin{figure}
\rule{\textwidth}{1cm}
\caption{bild}\label{bild}
\end{figure}

Siehe \vref{sec}, siehe \vref{bild}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Moving hyperref to after titlesec fixed the warnings I was getting "The anchor of a bookmark and its parent's must not be the same."