# How to solve hyperref anchor warnings?

Tags: floats, hyperref, warnings

I'm writing a report document, at some point I create a new section inside a chapter and I got this message from sharetex LaTeX compiler:

> main.tex:122 [hyperref] The anchor of a bookmark and its parent's must not be the same. Added a new anchor. (page 3)
>
> undefined:undefined `!h' float specifier changed to` !ht'. (page 3)

It looks like two different problems however I have no clue about what is causing the second one, since I have no `!h` statement.

This is a Minimum non Working Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
    \item {\bf Finalização} onde são finalizados os histogramas, eventualmente traçadas curvas de ajuste \emph{(fit)} e guardados os resultados no disco.
\end{itemize}

\chapter{Contextualização}
\section{Modelo de dados}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show a [minimal (non) working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Are you not inserting any float?

Comment: @Sigur I have some images, but all after page 3, none of them with `!h` notation

Comment: @egreg I it going to take some minutes ;)

Comment: The "anchor" problem seems to stem from some interaction between `varioref` and `cleverer`; I don't get any warning if I don't load one out of those two packages. Do you really need to use both anyway?

Comment: no idea, I just this headers from a friend. But the warning wasn't here at the beginning of this document

Comment: It seems to be triggered by `\section{...}`. I don't know the details but `cleverer` and `varioref` must alter the behaviour of `\section` in some slightly incompatible way. One question: do you get the other warning (!h) with the current MWE? I don't get that one at all.

Comment: Anyway, I can comment one of them if I got error means I'm using ;)

Comment: See this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53193/4427 According to it, the order is `varioref`, `hyperref` and `cleveref`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Jubobs suggestion:

I remove varioref package and the warning disappeared, I didn't get any errors by removing so apparently I wasn't using.

Comment: No need to mention me in your answer :)

Comment: it is your credit :)