# Hyperref causing cleveref to not reference equation ranges properly

Tags: equations, hyperref, cross-referencing, texstudio, cleveref

I'm having some trouble with referencing a range of equations. I've read several posts about how to do this using the cleveref package, but every solution posted results in my document having ??-?? shown in my pdf. I'm using TexStudio on a Mac.

I have located the source of the problem. If I have the hyperref package included, then it fails to work and produces only the ??-?? in the document. Is there some sort of fundamental incompatibility with those two packages?

My minimal working example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}  %For giving equations numbers like 1.1 ,etc
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:heatFluxVector}
\begin{aligned}
q_j &= -\lambda \frac{\partial T}{\partial x_j} + \rho \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{N} h_k Y_k V_{k,j}\\
& = -\lambda \frac{\partial T}{\partial x_j} - \rho \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{N} h_k D_k \frac{\partial Y_k}{\partial x_j}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where $\lambda$ is the thermal conductivity. The laminar Prandtl number, $Pr_L$ is defined as:

\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:laminarPrandtlNumberDefinition}
Pr_{L} = \frac{C_p \mu }{\lambda}  
\end{equation}

The conservation equations \crefrange{eqn:heatFluxVector}{eqn:laminarPrandtlNumberDefinition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) No incompatability but the order matters, `hyperref` should be loaded before `cleveref`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. It is to load cleveref after hyperref.

Related stack exchange post(see the accepted answer): [Impact of hyperref, when varioref and cleveref are used](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53191/impact-of-hyperref-when-varioref-and-cleveref-are-used)